# Selenium regex for trademark?

Tags: regex, selenium

I'm new to regex and selenium in general but I have to asser t that a text simmilar to this:

`© Negurici 2012. All rights reserved. Email: negurici@gmail.com`

Exists within the site, mostly I have to check that a neguric@something.com exists and I'm trying to do this with a regex expression:

```
<tr>
    <td>assertTextPresent</td>
    <td>regexp:©+[A-Z0-9.-]+negurici+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,6}$.</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

I'm thinking the trademark is the one causing the problems but I haven't found a example which deals only with the selenium ide.

Has anybody else encountered a similar problem or is there something obvious which I'm missing?

Comment: Are you sure it's a single character and not for example `&copy;`?

Comment: When I have selenium itself create the assert text it uses the symbol and not &copy so that's why I used it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One reason your pattern doesn't work is that you have forgotten to describe all the spaces.

Try this:

```
regexpi:negurici@[A-Z0-9.-]+
```

*regexpi* is the same than *regexp* but it is case-insensitive.

Comment: You're right I failed to take into account those, mostly I don't care for the start of the expresion I just need a regex which will accept anithing until the negurici@gmail.com part and I've tried a lot of examples but they didn't work.

Comment: This one works, could you please explain why regexpi works google is telling me it's a matlab function but it must be more to it.